# How to run pure typescript project in a browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created pure typescript project, but I have problems with import/export. I have error in console "ReferenceError: exports is not defined". After I run tsc command, I open the project by "Go live" extensions in visual studio code.

This is my code:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es5", "es6"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

index.ts:

```
import { BoardUI } from './app/BoardUI';
    
const boardUI = new BoardUI();
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <script type="module" src="../dist/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `"module": "commonjs",` in your tsconfig.json.

Otherwise you could change the module to `ES6` and your target to `ES2018`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers are now supporting `esmodule (esm)` natively. So you just simply output `esm` module should work then. Just keep in mind, Typescript will output module based on the `target` you set (which is default: `es3`. `es3`/`es5` will output with `CommonJS`)

To sum up, just specify the module from `es2015` should work:

```
"module": "es2015",
```

Comment: Now I've got error in console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) BoardUI:1 "

Comment: I dont know why but the BoardUI.js file is not even loaded to browser.

Comment: I think I found the error. 
Typescript wrong compiles index.ts to index.js. The error is the path of the imported file, in index.js the path looks like this: `import { BoardUI } from './app/BoardUI';`, and it should look like this: `import { BoardUI } from './app/BoardUI.js';` - it missing "js" extension

Comment: I have no idea why you said so since tsc will prioritize `.ts` files and only allow `.js` files as you set in the config with `allowJs: true`